# SwiftUI ProgressView in List can only be displayed once

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am working on a feature which takes a few seconds. So I want to display a `ProgressView` when my logic is in progress.

Not sure if this is a bug in SwiftUI, but in the following code, when I click the button the second time, the progress view does not show up anymore (The first click is fine tho)

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var inProgress = false
  var body: some View {
    List {
      if inProgress {
        HStack {
          Text("Waiting...")
          ProgressView()
        }
      } else {
        Button("Click Me") {
          inProgress = true
          Task {
            try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(2 * 1_000_000_000))
            inProgress = false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this problem only happens under a `List`. If I change it to a `VStack`, then the `ProgressView` is displayed every time I click the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show the `ProgressView` every time you click, add a new `.id()` to the `HStack` (or the ProgressView), so that it gets re-drawn:

```
    HStack {
      Text("Waiting...")
      ProgressView()
    }.id(UUID())  // <--- here
```

Note, you can also use `Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))`

Comment: It worked....could you provide more details why this works? When displaying other components (like `Text`), i did not provide this `id`

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly why since the code (ProgressView etc...) are not available. It seems some sort of optimisation of the views (List).